# Does Keras official sample code about Transformer applied in time-series contain Position Embedding part?

Tags: keras, time-series, transformer-model

The sample code for referring from url:https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/

I could not find out any description about "Position Embedding" content in full page of above url. When I looked through Transformer applied in NLP, I can clearly see the class named "TokenAndPositionEmbedding".

If it does not contain "Position Embedding", how can I apply Position Embedding in time series in sample code?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this? This [post](https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/transformer-implementation-for-time-series-forecasting-a9db2db5c820) i saw just generated more features as a stand-in to the positional embedding.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell it does not contain the positional embedding. Something like this should work.

```
class PositionEmbeddingFixedWeights(Layer):
def __init__(self, sequence_length, vocab_size, output_dim, **kwargs):
    super(PositionEmbeddingFixedWeights, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    word_embedding_matrix = self.get_position_encoding(vocab_size, output_dim)   
    position_embedding_matrix = self.get_position_encoding(sequence_length, output_dim)                                          
    self.word_embedding_layer = Embedding(
        input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=output_dim,
        weights=[word_embedding_matrix],
        trainable=False
    )
    self.position_embedding_layer = Embedding(
        input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=output_dim,
        weights=[position_embedding_matrix],
        trainable=False
    )
         
def get_position_encoding(self, seq_len, d, n=10000):
    P = np.zeros((seq_len, d))
    for k in range(seq_len):
        for i in np.arange(int(d/2)):
            denominator = np.power(n, 2*i/d)
            P[k, 2*i] = np.sin(k/denominator)
            P[k, 2*i+1] = np.cos(k/denominator)
    return P


def call(self, inputs):        
    position_indices = tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[-1])
    embedded_words = self.word_embedding_layer(inputs)
    embedded_indices = self.position_embedding_layer(position_indices)
    return embedded_words + embedded_indices
```

This class originated from https://machinelearningmastery.com/the-transformer-positional-encoding-layer-in-keras-part-2/

Comment: so to make it the same as the keras timeseries transformers tutorial, we would set d=1? since its a multivariate timeseries?

Comment: univariate* also I think this line --  `word_embedding_matrix = self.get_position_encoding(vocab_size, output_dim)` -- is wrong. shouldn't that jus be the regular embedding? positional embedding is on the next lilne...

Comment: also, I'm not sure this standard positional encoding even makes sense with d=1. We would have only one sinusoid, so there's no way positions would be uniquely determined by the encoding

Comment: As currently written it would only work for univariate. You are correct about the word_embedding_matrix. The weight initialization there should be remkved and it should be trainable.

Comment: The d paramter is the output dimensions. Each word is encoded then repeated and added to the positional encoding over d dimendions.

Comment: For a multivariate series you would need separate word embeddings for each feature.